# How to get firebase user custom token fields?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using custom token method to authenticate in firebase. In my server I generate custom token using some fields, like

`{ "uid" : "user_uid", "phone_number": "93423423" }`

And getting the data like

```
(String) firebaseRef.getAuth().get("phone_number")
```

But how to to get the data in new firebase (`com.google.firebase`), where `FirebaseUser` class is used.